# css file in template Symfony 3 twig

Tags: twig, symfony

I would like to know if it's possible to include my css file directly in my template file. 
Here is my template in a separate html.twig file:

```
 {% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/assets/vendor/checkbox-awesome/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block checkbox_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
            <label style="font-weight:700;color:#333;" for="{{ id }}"><span>{{ label|trans }}</span></label>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

I use this template to generate customs checkboxes. 
This block stylesheets doesn't work, I have to include it in each html file which contains checkboxes. 
Thanks for your help :) 
    (Sorry for my english mistakes)

Comment: What is the exact location in relation to your Symfony project? I'm wondering if you actually have an "assets" folder or not? Normally there is just a "vendor" folder under the root Symfony folder.